# Pintar célula de acordo com datas no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma planilha de controle de atividades, ela contém uma tabela com "inicio previsto" e outra com "término previsto", dentro dessa tabela tem datas como exemplo:

24/07/19 formatada para deixar nessa condição.

Minha dúvida é, gostaria de ao inserir uma data, fosse colorido o dia da semana da mesma, contabilizado a partir do dia atual.
Tentei com várias formulas como exemplo WEEKDAY; TODAY. E ambos não apresentaram o resultado esperado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Creio que não haja ou seja muito complexo realizar isso somente com fórmulas do Excel. E ao trabalhar com semanas, há alguns problemas que podem ocorrer, pois o ano possui 365[,25] dias. Então é recomendada a [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), enfim, você pode criar um programa em VBA para realizar isso, pois não vi uma maneira de realizar isso facilmente com formatação condicional. Mas você pode pegar o número da semana com `NÚMSEMANA` ou `WEEKNUM`. E fazer uma formatação condicional para cada conjunto de colunas de semanas. Trabalhoso...

Answer (score 1):

[image: Tente algo parecido com isso]

substitua o primeiro valor "1" nas outras fórmulas pelo valor da semana correspondente ao dia, por exemplo, Segunda =1 , Terça =2